# How to get Mail on iOS 8 to automatically interpret contact details

Tags: ios, email, ios8

As a new feature in iOS 8, the Mail app will now display a dialog at the top of the screen with the contact information that is automatically pulled from within the email (generally the signature of the sender).  A quick example of this feature is posted below (taken from Ars Technica's iOS 8 review available [here](http://arstechnica.com/apple/2014/09/ios-8-thoroughly-reviewed/8/#mail)):

[image]

After looking several emails with a variety of different email signatures, it seems that this feature has rather narrow requirements in order for the information to be successful extracted.  Does anyone know what these restrictions are or how to format a signature so that it will always be picked up by Mail?

Comment: What is the programming part of this question?

Comment: @rmaddy I left out the specific programming aspects of the question because I recognized that this issue occurs at a higher level than my particular problem.  While asking "What changes should I make to my Outlook 2008 add-in so that contact information in my automatically generated HTML signatures are interpreted by Mail on iOS 8" would be more helpfully to me, it is a question that is less helpful to the community.  If this is too general for the site and people feel it should be closed, I will be happy to rephrase the question to highlight the exact programming issue I am looking to solve.